# TFS: task auto closed when check in but effort hours not updated

Tags: tfs

I'm using TFS under VS2013. After I checked in some of my code, the current task has been changed to 'Closed' automatically. This is not bad so far.

However, the Remaining/Completed fields in the Effort section are not changed. These seem very strange to me.

What should I do with the Effort fields? Should I update them after the task is CLOSED?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a check in through Visual Studio, it asks for you to give a Work Item, and once you have chosen the work item in the right it appear something like "Resolve" or "Associate".

You need to take care, because by default is in "Resolve", then, your first check in, if you don´t change it, it will be closed and you will need to reopen.

The solution, change from "resolve" to "Associate" each time you do a check in ;) 
I believe that there is no automatic way to do it! And if you find it... please, let me know hehehe

Comment: Thanks! I think the 'Resolve when check in' is OK to me. But the fact that the Effort fields not updated confuses me. Why does TFS not update both the status and the completed hours/remaining hours together? Or, the Effort fields are designed to be updated manually?

Comment: I think that it´s designated to fill manually Zach ;) At least is the way I do!

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but I thought it might help someone. In Visual Studio 2017 this option is available to be configured as below:
Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Visual Studio Team Foundation Server -> Resolve associated work items on check-in. Uncheck that box and it will not Resolve the linked tasks automatically.

Hope this helps.

See the image below from Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017

[image]